# osmdroid android app using BingMapTileSource

Tags: java, android, gps, bing-maps, osmdroid

I'm trying to make an android app using osmdroid that will have a satellite view. I need Bing Maps to be able to do this. I have the app working with Mapquest road maps but I'm running into a small error. I need to call the method

```
BingMapTileSource.initMetaData(this);
```

but I am getting the error 
"initMetaData() has private access in 'org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.bing.BingMapTileSource'. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources

Under manifest/application

`<meta-data android:name="BING_KEY" android:value="YOUR KEY" />`

Code Sample:

`//load from manifest
org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.bing.BingMapTileSource.retrieveBingKey(this);
//or load programmatically
org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.bing.BingMapTileSource.setBingKey("YOUR KEY");
org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.bing.BingMapTileSource bing=new org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.bing.BingMapTileSource(null);
mapView.setTileSource(bing);`

Comment: It cannot resolve setBingKey as a method for some reason.

Comment: Update your dependencies

Comment: org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.bing.BingMapTileSource.retrieveBingKey(this);
 org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.bing.BingMapTileSource bing=new org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.bing.BingMapTileSource(null);
 bing.setStyle(BingMapTileSource.IMAGERYSET_AERIAL);
 mapView.setTileSource(bing);                                                                                 does not work for some reason.

Comment: What should my dependencies be? right now I have                                    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.3'
    compile files('/libs/osmdroid-third-party-4.3.jar')
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.12'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

Comment: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-add-the-osmdroid-library-via-Gradle

Comment: After adding the @aar file my app crashes soon as it opens

Comment: Look at the log output.

Comment: Sadly the log just looks like a bunch of nothing to me

Comment: should probably consult the change log. https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Changelog maybe you're using an API that needs to be updated